# Adding dynamic text boxes in windows store app 8.1 using xaml c#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows

```
TextBox x = new TextBox();
x.Height = 30;
x.Width = 200;
x.Name = "Title";
x.Text = item.Title;
x.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;

x.FontSize = 60;

StackPanel s = new StackPanel();
s.Children.Add(x);
```

I have placed this code inside a function called **private async void Getnotes();**
and im calling this function from the constructor after **this.InitializeComponent();**

But when i run the app,**text boxes are not getting added**. what could be the problem?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `stackpanel` to the window

```
window.AddChild(s);
```

You need to pass the `window` to your function.

Comment: 'SecureCase.BlankPage1' does not contain a definition for 'AddChild' and no extension method 'AddChild' accepting a first argument of type 'SecureCase.BlankPage1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) getting this error when i try to add that @Empereur

Comment: Partially,. but how to pass the window as a parameter

Comment: Are you using a window or a page? Eitherway, your method should have a parameter of type window or page. Then call your method like this: `Getnotes(this);` in the constructor of your page or window...
If you are using a page, the way to add children will be different. But you can search it up

Comment: this.StackPanel.Children.Add(x); Finally this worked,Thank u for your response

Answer (score 0):

by default wpf app has a non named grid.
name it "MyMainGrid".

and then you can add ether your stack panel.

```
MyMainGrid.Children.Add(s);
```

or directly add textbox to grid.

```
MyMainGrid.Children.Add(X);
```

Comment: Sorry this is not working.. I dont know what is the problem,,

Comment: this.StackPanel.Children.Add(x); Finally this worked,Thank u for your response